# Getting logged out automatically while watching YouTube in full screen mode

Tags: video, session

I was watching YouTube videos and I clicked full screen mode. Then I was suddenly logged out of my Ubuntu system and the start page appeared asking for username and password. This happens randomly at least 5 times a day. When I log in, the crash report GUI prompt comes up.

I went to the `/var/crash` folder. There are files such as

```
_usr_bin_totem-video-thumbnailer.1000.crash
_usr_bin_totem-video-thumbnailer.1000.upload
_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash
```

I don't know what to do. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: if this doesn't only happen when watching videos in full screen, please remove that part from the title and clarify in your question that it happens regardless of what you are doing

Comment: It only happens when watching youtube videos. However I watch youtube videos a lot. So I'm not sure if it is coincident or not. Today kernel 4.13 upgrade came into upgrade. Let me see the issue consistent. Thanks Zanna as always. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble with Chromium browser on Debian 11 and LXDE desktop.
I have installed Firefox-ESR this is an alternative for now.